# NGRX Effect With Two Chained API Responses is Not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-effects

I am using below code to create an ngrx effect which is dependent on two API responses. Data from APIResponseone is neeeded to trigger APIResponseTwo and then an action should be dispatched based on response from APIResponseTwo. This gives me an error at second switchMap.

Argument of type '(resArray: any) => Observable<Content[]> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput'.
Type 'Observable<Content[]> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'

```
    getFinalResponse$ = createEffect(
  () =>
    this.actions.pipe(
      ofType<Action & { request: apiRequest }>(
        ActionTypes.GetDetails
      ),
      switchMap(({ request }) => {
        const payload: apiRequest = request;
        return this.apiServiceOne
          .getDetails(payload)
          .pipe(
            map((response) => {
              let resArray: PData[] = [];
              if (
                response.arrayOne &&
                response.arrayOne.length > 0
              ) {
                resArray =
                  response &&
                  response.arrayOne.filter(
                    (options) =>
                      options.id === "TEST1234"
                  );
              }
              return resArray;
            }) //map
          )
          .pipe(
            switchMap((resArray: any) => {
              if (resArray && resArray.length > 0) {
                const secondReq: any = {
                  type: ['idtype']
                };
                return this.apiServiceTwo
                  .getData(secondReq)
                  .pipe(
                    map((triggers) => {
                      let finalArray: Content[] = [];
                      if (
                        triggers.arraytwo &&
                        triggers.arraytwo.length > 0
                      ) {
                        finalArray =
                          triggers.arraytwo.filter(
                            (opts) =>
                              opts.info &&
                              opts.info.selected
                          );
                      }
                      return finalArray;
                    }) //map
                  );
              }
            }) //switchmap2 close bracket
          ) // pipe
          .pipe(
            map((result) => {
              return loadedRes({
                response: result
              });
            }),
            catchError((error) => of(loadedError({ error })))
          );
      })
    ) //actions pipe
);
```

Comment: May I suggest you start by placing all of your operators in the top-level pipe? That will clean things up for you and for us :)

Comment: In the second `switchMap` you are not returning anything if this condition `if (resArray && resArray.length > 0)` is `false`.